# Reading I2C register with regmap_read() but getting constant values

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

This might actually be a question about how `regmap.c` works in general but, currently, I do have a specific question regarding the usage of `regmap_read()`.

I am studying and modifying a reference driver implementation for a ov5693 camera to be used in a Jetson TX1 (using nVidia code example, provided in the  *[NVIDIA Tegra Linux Driver Package Development Guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/dlc/l4t-documentation-24-1)*). The way I understand it is that, the camera has MIPI CSI-2 data that is treated by nVidia's driver "somewhere else" and the part I am modifying is the I2C part of the driver, where it is defined as a V4L2 subdevice and registers my camera as an I2C device and, there, I'm also able to implement some external V4L2 commands to be called via `ioctl()`.

The driver's main functionalities are working according to what I expected. I'm able to capture frames and writing (via `write_reg()`) different values to the register related to the 'gain' in the sensor does result in changes in the images I capture.

Then, I wrote a simple function to be called by through a custom V4L2 `ioctl` command, to print the value of a register at a given address (to be read at `dmesg`). What I do is, roughly, something among the lines of

```
test_function(struct camera_common_data *s_data, unsigned int val){
    struct ov5693 *priv = (struct ov5693 *)s_data->priv;
    int err;
    u16 address;
    u8 value;

    address = (u16)(val & 0xffff);
    err = read_reg(priv->regmap, (unsigned int)address, (unsigned int *)(&value));
    printk("debug: %s: addr=0x%04X, val=0x%02X\n", __func__, address, value);
}
```

The struct `ov5693` contains various V4L2 structs and other variables, and regmap is of the correct type to be passed to `read_reg()`.

So, this function does print values that, mostly, happen to match the default values indicated in the sensor datasheet.

*And here is where my trouble begins*. **Even though I *know* that I've been indeed able to write values to the I2C register** (as I've mentioned before, I wrote different values for the register related to the 'gain' of the sensor, and I was able capture different images, each image having changed in the expected way, appropriately to the 'gain' value) **whenever I try to read the same register, even after writing different values, it always shows the same (initial) value**.

It seems to me like I'm somehow reading from a kind of cached version of the register(?). If that's the case, I couldn't really understand either how or why it happens. Or I might even be misunderstanding the whole process of how `regmap.c` works.

All I wanted to do was to be able to read the *actual* value stored in the register, but so far I think I didn't get anywhere closer to that.

Do anyone happen to know something about this? Might be something about `regmap.c` that I'm neglecting or something about the way my device's register map is set (if that's the case, what exactly)? I would be grateful for any hints, leads or advices!

Comment: 1. Which exactly kernel version do you use? 2. Can you try `regmap_raw_read()` instead?

Comment: 1. `uname -r` returns me `3.10.96+`, but I'm using [nVidia's provided source code](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/dlc/l4t-24-1-kernel-sources).
2. Tried `regmap_raw_read()` now, but its behavior was the same as the regular one.

Comment: I think that there might be some bug in regmap implementation in kernel. `git log v3.10..HEAD -- drivers/base/regmap/` in mainline kernel shows a huge delta. Can you check if some patches from that delta look like fix for your problem? I'd search for "cache" word in that `git log` output for starters, starting from oldest patches up to newest ones... Also, is there any chance you can try the same code on newer kernel? Another explanation is that register value in hardware is actually the one you get. Can you try some direct I2C access to confirm that?

Comment: Now, that's definitely somewhat trickier to test, because the fork I'm using probably already has some nVidia-specific customizations. Then, naively substituting the `regmap/` folder, as I expected, broke the compilation, but I didn't go too far on this case. I tried just substituting `regmap_read()` and `_regmap_read()` code and that got me the same behavior as before. Trying to substitute `regmap_raw_read()` and `_regmap_raw_read()` was far more complicated and I ultimately couldn't do it manually. (cont'd)

Comment: (...) There's still the possibility for me to try another kernel version, but I do have some other more urgent tasks to do. For now I think this probably has to do with what you said about it being on the hardware side of things. As for the I2C direct access, I'm not really sure about how to do it correctly. I tried `i2cdump -f` but it gets me a table full of `XX`s and `dmesg` shows a `no acknowledge from address 0x**` for each read (I tested this with my camera driver both enabled and disabled, same result).

Comment: For direct I2C access -- I meant, do that from your kernel code (driver). See [Documentation/i2c/writing-clients](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/writing-clients) for details ("Sending and receiving" section). Of course, just replacing the file from newer kernel version won't work. You need to `git cherry-pick` relevant patches, or pull them by hand. But it's easier to test your driver on new kernel first. If bug persists -- it's not about fixing `regmap` framework. And if raw I2C read shows you the same value (on your old kernel version) -- then it's your hardware behavior.

Comment: So I tried reading with `i2c_master_recv()` and it, once again, got me the same value. Guess it really is the hardware behavior then. (btw, huge thanks, Sam!)

Comment: Some of the hardware might have so called **write-only** registers. Look at datasheet for your device in question to see if it's the case. Another possibility that special sequence to flush values before read is needed.